# How to scale up image into thumbnail without distorting it?

Tags: post-thumbnails, scale

I have a section in my single post page that contains the post thumbnail. When using a smaller image as featured image (smaller than the thumbnail size, in width or height) it gets distorted to fill the thumbnail and lose its proportion. When the featured image is bigger than the thumbnail size or at least has a similar proportion, it seems to work just fine.

An image showing the case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKR5z.jpg

Here's all the code I used:

```
add_image_size( 'thumbpost', 698, 320, true );

<div class="thumbpost"><?php { the_post_thumbnail('thumbpost' ); } ?></div>

.thumbpost{
  width:100%;
  height:320px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.thumbpost img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Wordpress generates an image maintaining the original width, that is smaller than the thumbnail's width that I want

Comment: WordPress is not doing anything, it's not cropping images smaller than featured image size. The issue is in your CSS where you are asking your images to size `100%` width and `320px` height.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using 100% because it's inside another div with the width in px I need. Therefore, I used 100% to fill all the width available. (http://i.imgur.com/XtdpuyV.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that's what wrong. Let's say your image is `300 x 200 px` size. Now if your div's width is `600px` and height `320px` and you are asking your images to fill `100%` width and height of parent div then your image will resize (not crop) with CSS for `600px x 320px` and will look distorted.

Comment: Using your case: can't Wordpress generate a 600x400 image from the original 300x200 so it gets cropped by the div's sizes 600x320? (if it doesn't there's only two options: either it gets distorted or it doesn't fill the size I set?)

Comment: No, WordPress cannot do that. It can not upscale. If any dimension (width or height) of a image is larger then defined size, then it will crop image to scale down that dimension.

Comment: Well, I managed to get the upscaling by using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-upscale/ (which uses a code from a question from this very forum) but it ignores the crop position set in the add_image_size line. I'll keep looking around for a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem that you're running into is that WordPress isn't actually doing anything to your images, because it doesn't upscale images. You can use hooks to modify WordPress' behavior without hacking core, or you can try to fix the issue with CSS.

### Changing WordPress to Upscale Thumbnails

[ALXMedia has an useful example](http://alxmedia.se/code/2013/10/thumbnail-upscale-correct-crop-in-wordpress/) on adding this behavior. Excerpt below.

```
// Upscale thumbnails when the source image is smaller than the thumbnail size. Retain the aspect ratio.
function alx_thumbnail_upscale( $default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h, $crop ){
    if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'alx_thumbnail_upscale', 10, 6 );
```

### Fixing it with CSS

The issue in CSS is that you have an image that has different proportions compared to it's container (because it's not upscaling nor cropping), and you're setting *both* the height and width to 100%. What you should instead do is to set one of those dimensions to 100% (the width in this case) and the other to auto. Assuming you want to mimic the crop, you can set the overflow on the parent div to hidden in order to crop it. This will only crop the bottom however, so you'll need to play around with margins or other positioning tricks to make it appear like a centered crop.

Here's an example of what the correct css might look like:

```
.thumbpost{
    width:100%;
    height:320px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.thumbpost img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```